# Disable theme WooCommerce template

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, templates, wp-config

Just purchased a premium WooCommerce-read theme. Unfortunately, this theme comes with a /woocommerce folder. How can I disable this templates,without deleting whole folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many themes overwrite WooCommerce template files. A behaviour that can cause malfunctions.

WC_TEMPLATE_DEBUG_MODE will prevent overrides in themes from taking priority

```
// Add this to wp-config.php file

define( 'WC_TEMPLATE_DEBUG_MODE', true );
```

https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_template_part.html